# JSONDecodeError when running instabot-py

Tags: python, python-3.x

try to install the Instabot-py (https://pypi.org/project/instabot-py/). And get an error when running the script.

My workaround:

1. first, installed the by: python3 -m pip install instabot-py
2. I fill in the information that was needed
3. try to run the run the script by command: python3 -m instabot_py
4. get these error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/bin/instabot-py",
> line 8, in sys.exit(main()) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instabot_py/main.py", line
> 357, in main bot = InstaBot(config=config) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instabot_py/instabot.py", line
> 219, in init self.login() File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instabot_py/instabot.py", line
> 316, in login login_response = login.json() File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 897,
> in json return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs) File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/init.py",
> line 357, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s) File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py",
> line 337, in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py",
> line 355, in raw_decode raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s,
> err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value:
> line 1 column 1 (char 0)

And i'm not so good, that i know what to do. So hopefully someone can help.